# CppCoreChecker C-Style cast warning when using range based for loop on vector

Tags: c++, c++11, static-analysis, cpp-core-guidelines

Assume the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines;
    lines.push_back("line");
    for (const auto& s : lines) {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

At the line of the for loop I get the following warning:

> C26493 Don't use C-style casts that would perform a static_cast downcast, const_cast, or reinterpret_cast.

Can someone explain where this is coming from? Im using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition Version 15.2.

Comment: It surely looks like a VS bug.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As seen in [this bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/26398/c-core-check-false-positive-c26493-when-inserting.html) it seems to happen only for the `std::string` type when inserting into a `basic_iostream`. This bug has been resolved but hasn't been released yet so for now you'll just have to wait.